# How to eliminate the text "[n] lines folded"

Tags: vim

I would like a folded line to display only "-" characters: no text at all.

I have tried defining foldtext per examples here and in help:.  I was able to eliminate the first line contents, which were extremely annoying and completely illogical to my thinking, but it still displays

```
---"3 lines folded"-------
```

for example.

(For me it is visually distracting and irrelevant...partly defeats the purpose of folding for me, which is to HIDE the collapsed section, not to HIGHLIGHT it, which is what this redundant message does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not say what you tried that did not work, but with

```
:set foldtext='---'
```

I see a line of dashes (full width) in place of the fold.  If you want even less distraction than that, try

```
:set fillchars+=fold:\   foldtext='\ '
```

(There are two spaces after the first backslash.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following settings in your .vimrc:

```
set foldtext=EmptyFoldText()
function! EmptyFoldText()
return '-'
endfunction
```

Works fine on my vim.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I combined this with answer from benjifisher. BTW, what is the reason for creating and calling a function, rather than just doing set foldtext="-"?

Comment: There is no reason to create function in this case. Function can be helpful if you want to print some something special.